# Ternary Operator on Boto3

Tags: json, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Saw some code related to serializing typical JSON object to DynamoDB JSON format. Link is provided here
Question really is why he used the ternary operator (`x if c then y`) when he could have just fed `item` into the method.

I had tested in my Lambda environment, and saw that when you create a python object (`pyObject = someJSON`), and you try to get its `.__dict__` attribute, you'll get an attribute error. So just feeding the pyObject into `.serialize` will work. Why do the ternary operator?

Is he unsure if the `.__dict__` attribute is available or even existent?

Code snippet below:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeSerializer, TypeDeserializer
import json

serializer = TypeSerializer()
deserializer = TypeDeserializer()

# for building a DynamoDB JSON from a Python object
def serialize(item):
    serialized_item = serializer.serialize(vars(item) if hasattr(item, '__dict__') else item)

    return item if 'M' not in serialized_item else serialized_item['M']

# for building a plain JSON from a DynamoDB JSON
def deserialize(dynamodb_json_string):
    return deserializer.deserialize({'M': dynamodb_json_string})

class MyItem:
    def __init__(self, some_string_value=None, some_numeric_value=None):
        self.my_key = some_string_value
        self.my_other_key = some_numeric_value

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_classy_item = MyItem("my_string_value", 5)
    my_string_item = json.loads('{"my_key": "my_string_value", "my_other_key" : 5}')

    print(serialize(my_classy_item))
    print(serialize(my_string_item))
```

The code worked as expected. Was just wondering why the ternary operator was used

Comment: "Question really is why he used the ternary operator": that's something only "he" can answer. Could you please reformulate your question so that anyone could answer it?

Comment: They want to convert the object to a dictionary if possible when serializing. `vars(item)` will get an error if there's no `__dict__` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use this format:

```
serializer = TypeSerializer()
serialized_item = serializer.serialize(item_to_store)
```

You can read more on converting between JSON types here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about why the original code was written that way.

Comment: Only the author can answer that, and rather than letting the question go unanswered I provided my knowledge on the matter. Thanks for your input.